# Using CSS property calc() with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am needing to use the css calc() property to displace an element on the screen. Works fine if I do it via CSS however this CSS property need to be displaced by 50% - a variable worked out in JS.

See this example:

```
var displace = childHeight / 2
parent.css({'top': 'calc( 50% -' + displace + 'px)'});
```

When this runs however, it does not get applied to the HTML element on the page. To clarify that this DOES work with other stuff, if I were to type:

```
parent.css({'top': '50px'});
```

This would work and i've tested it and it applies. This means that there is an issue with applying the calc() via JS to a css element. Perhaps it is the way I have concatenated the variable into the calc().

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: what is `parent`? elements dont have  a `.css()` method. are you talking about jquery

Comment: This is JQuery method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space after the minus letter :

```
var displace = childHeight / 2;
$(".test").css({'top': 'calc(50% - ' + displace + 'px)'});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/m9mmhhyq/2/)

Comment: 1 character.... ONE CHARACTER! Thank you so much! will mark as answer as soon as Stack lets me!

Answer (score 1):

The `+` and `-` operators must always be surrounded by whitespace. So you have to add an extra space here:

```
//                             |-  === HERE ===
parent.css({'top': 'calc( 50% - ' + displace + 'px)'});
```